# how to check string value apache uima ruta

Tags: string, apache, uima, ruta

As per the example earlier, First Name and Last Name on this website, I am trying to advance code a bit. So, I want to make FULL Name only for those where Genders are matched, if First Name is marked as male then Last Name should be also male.

The error is in the last line, however i am not sure about the whole part starting from GENDER Wordtable. See below

```
    PACKAGE com.test.fullnameannotator;
    WORDTABLE firstNames = 'FirstName.csv';
    DECLARE Annotation firstName(STRING fnValue, STRING fnGender);
    Document{->MARKTABLE(firstName ,1, firstNames, "fnValue" = 2, "fnGender"=3)};
    WORDTABLE lastNames = 'LastName.csv';
    DECLARE Annotation lastName(STRING lnValue, STRING lnGender);
    Document{->MARKTABLE(lastName ,1, lastNames, "lnValue" = 2, "lnGender"=3)};
    WORDTABLE Gender = 'Gender.csv';
    DECLARE Annotation Gender_a (STRING FNGender); 
    DECLARE Annotation FLName (firstName fnValue, lastName lnValue);
    Document{CONTAINS (Gender_a) -> CREATE (FLName, "fnValue" = firstName, "lnValue" = lastName)};
    (e1:firstName # Gender_a # e2:lastName) {-> FLName, FLName.fnValue=e1, FLName.lnValue=e2};
```

Comment: Can you extend the quetion with some text examples. It is not clear how the last two rules relate.

Comment: Maybe something like `(e1:firstName e2:lastName) {e1.fnGender == e2.lnGender -> FLName, FLName.fnValue=e1, FLName.lnValue=e2};`?

Answer (score 0):

String values in features of annotations can be checked and compared in UIMA Ruta using different language elements.

The most natural way is using the dot notation in order to access the feature values and then using a boolean expression for comparison, e.g.,

```
(e1:firstName e2:lastName) {e1.fnGender == e2.lnGender -> FLName, FLName.fnValue=e1, FLName.lnValue=e2};
```

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*